# Search results only for the current language

Tags: 8, search

I have a site with 4 languages and am using the builtin search to look for content on the site. How is it possible to restrict the search results only to the currently selected language?

I tried looking into Configuration > Search Pages, but do not see any way how to do that there.

Comment: Are you using solr search or normal search with some view ?

Comment: I don't use a view for this. I am using the out-of-the-box search that you get on a fresh install of D8. The only way I found to modify the behavior of the search is either through Configuration > Search Pages or via twig templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Advanced" core search has this built in. If you prefer to do this from a theme - you could do it with form_alter. This basically hides the advanced search settings and sets current language as the only language to get results from, in the search block and search page.

Alternately you can just allow users to control which language they want to get results from and simply allow them to use advanced search.

Code for theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function hook_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['help_link']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['advanced']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['basic']['keys']['#title'] = '';
  $manager = \Drupal::languageManager();
  $form['advanced']['lang-fieldset']['language']['#default_value'] = [$manager->getCurrentLanguage()->getId()];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function hook_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $manager = \Drupal::languageManager();

  $form['advanced-form'] = [
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 1,
  ];
  $form['f[0]'] = [
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'language:' . $manager->getCurrentLanguage()->getId(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. I tried adding the code above to mytheme.theme, cleared the cache and rebuilt, but there's no change. Anything else I might have to do?

Comment: @Ondrej Replace hook with theme name in functions

Comment: @googletorp thx for the suggestion, but changing "hook" with theme-name didn't work.
it should be put in mytheme.theme, no?

Comment: @jimi I think you may be misunderstanding. You rename the functions in the above code. So instead of "hook_form_search_form_alter" it would be "somecustomthemename_form_search_form_alter" this worked for me. I used this code and it works fine for me. Thanks googletorp.

Comment: This actually works for the search block form! Thanks! Is there anywhere with documentation about adding advanced filters this way? I can't find ANYTHING.

Comment: Isn't there a way to filter the results in the twig template?

Comment: Just tested it, the problem is that when you are on the search result page and then change the language the search language attribute in the URL is not changing, so the results remain in the first language.

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple way [`hook_query_TAG_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x). Example return node for current language.

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter(): tag search_$type with $type node_search.
 */
function MYMODULE_query_search_node_search_alter(AlterableInterface $query) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $query->condition('n.langcode', $language, '=');
}
```

Comment: Right, so there's really no inbuilt way to do this - at least I know that for sure now :) 

I'm not a module developer, so, can this be somehow done on the theme level (like in mytheme.theme maybe)?

Comment: Same question here, is this also possible on theme level?

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
 */    
function hook_query_search_node_search_alter(&$query) {
      $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
      $query->condition('i.langcode', [$language, 'und', 'zxx'], 'IN');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Instead of only providing code, I encourage you to extend the answer with an explanation/give more context (what is the difference with other answers).

Comment: There already is a similar answer, what exactly makes your answer different?

Comment: @leymannx The main difference seems to be that this code snippet includes results that have undefined language where as the code snippet from MrD is looking for results in the same language only).